# Getting a syntax error on a variable declaration in C

Tags: c, function, syntax, clion, definition

I see a syntax error when I run the debugger on the two variables I declare in CLion. I commented the debugger errors it shows me in the lines of the two variables.

```
int sum3or5Multiples() {

    int sum = 0;    // sum: error: A syntax error in expression, near `/mt sum`.
    int multipleOf3;    // multipleOf3: error: A syntax error in expression, near `/mt multipleOf3`
    for (multipleOf3 = 0; multipleOf3 < 1000; multipleOf3 + 3) {
        sum = sum + multipleOf3;
    }
    int multipleOf5;
    for (multipleOf5 = 0; multipleOf5 < 1000; multipleOf5 + 5) {
        sum = sum + multipleOf5;
        if ((3 * multipleOf5) < 1000) {
            sum = sum - (3 * multipleOf5);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: How did you run the program in a debugger if yout get syntax errors? This normally means the compiler cannot create any executable from your code. The lines you marked do not look bad.

Comment: I don't get any error from GCC. Only some warnings about statement with no effect. These are mentioned in Vlad's answer.

Comment: I guess CLion with the debugger my school chose to use does not want to give extra help such as warnings like that. @Gerhardh

Comment: I assume you have some mismatch between code in your editor and code that is really compiled. Maybe project settings are messed up? The code you showed definitely has no syntax error. I could imagine the compiling failed and you happened to still run the debugger that used some older executable.

Comment: Enabling warnings should be one of the first lessons to learn in a programming class.

Comment: BTW: A Debugger does not give any warnings. It does not look at the code at all. It is the compiler's job. You must learn to distinguish them. Otherwise you will run into lots of strange conversation. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you mean

```
multipleOf3 += 3
```

and

```
multipleOf5 += 5
```

instead of

```
multipleOf3 + 3
```

and

```
multipleOf5 + 5
```

With these changes the function compiles without errors.